# How can a floating point number be converted into an integer in ATS?

Tags: ats

For instance, I need to turn the number 3.14 (of the type double) into 3 (of the type int). I tried double2int but it did not work. I also tried floor, but it did not work, either.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `g0float2int`.

For example:

```
#include
"share/atspre_staload.hats"
#include
"share/atspre_staload_libats_ML.hats"

implement main0() = ()

val double_pi:double = 3.14
val int_pi:int = g0float2int(double_pi) 

val () = println!(double_pi)
val () = println!(int_pi)
```

You might be confused because there is a function in the ATS [codebase](https://github.com/githwxi/ATS-Postiats/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=double2int) called `double2int`, but it is unique to the libraries used to target certain languages like JavaScript, etc.